# What could be causing display corruption in a flash video player?

Tags: actionscript, video, flash

We're seeing some really gnarly display corruption in our flash video player.  Here's an example:

[image: Example screenshot of display corruption]
<sub>(source: [scottyallen.com](http://scottyallen.com/images/other_site_posts/corruption.png))</sub>

We're using fl.video.VideoPlayer for displaying our video, and it seem like perhaps this bug appears most when we're switching between different instances of VideoPlayer, particularly when there's something else above the VideoPlayer that is actively being redrawn.  It looks to me like maybe an uninitialized video buffer is getting painted when it shouldn't be.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Any ideas on how to further track down what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen glitches like that in Flash is when I've been doing extensive alpha stacking or pushing brightness filters above 100%.